# A way around having to loop through results to access more information using the first result set

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Given the following Database setup:

```
Customers
| customerId | accountId | addressId |
|------------|-----------|-----------|
|      1     |    110    |     8     |
|      2     |    120    |     9     |
|      3     |    130    |     10    |

Address
| addressId | companyName | state |
|-----------|-------------|-------|
|     8     |  FooBar Co  |   FL  |
|     9     |   Self Co   |   VA  |
|     10    |    Cli Co   |   CA  |

Tests
| testId | accountId | testType | Status  |
|--------|-----------|----------|---------|
|    1   |    120    |   Urine  |   Done  |
|    2   |    110    |   Blood  | Pending |
|    3   |    110    |   Blood  | Pending |
|    4   |    130    |  Biopsy  |   Done  |
|    5   |    130    |   Blood  |   Done  |
|    6   |    130    |   Urine  | Pending |
|    7   |    110    |  Biopsy  | Pending |
|    8   |    120    |   Urine  | Pending |
|    9   |    110    |  Biopsy  | Pending |
|   10   |    110    |   Urine  | Pending |
```

Is there a way for me to get around having to loop through a mysqli result set of customers in order to grab the COUNT of each testType based on the name of the type of test and based on the accountId. So for example I am currently doing this:

```
$sql = "SELECT C.accountId, A.companyName 
         FROM Customers C
         JOIN Address A
         ON C.addressId=A.addressId";

$result = mysqli_query($connection,  $sql);

$customers = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

foreach( $customers as $customer ) :
  echo '<h2>' . $customer["companyName"] . '</h2>';

  // Urine Tests Count
  $sql = 'SELECT COUNT(testId) as count FROM Tests WHERE accountId=' . $customer["accountId"] . ' AND testType="Urine"';
  $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
  $testCount = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
  echo '<p>Total Urine Tests: ' . $testCount["count"] . '</p>';

  // Biopsy Tests Count
  $sql = 'SELECT COUNT(testId) as count FROM Tests WHERE accountId=' . $customer["accountId"] . ' AND testType="Biopsy"';
  $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
  $testCount = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
  echo '<p>Total Biopsy Tests: ' . $testCount["count"] . '</p>';

  // Blood Tests Count
  $sql = 'SELECT COUNT(testId) as count FROM Tests WHERE accountId=' . $customer["accountId"] . ' AND testType="Blood"';
  $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
  $testCount = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
  echo '<p>Total Blood Tests: ' . $testCount["count"] . '</p>';
endforeach;
```

As you can probably tell this is hella repetative but so far it's been the only way to get the information I want. I know I could do a `COUNT()` with a `GROUP BY` for the tests once I am inside the foreach loop, but if I do that, I won't get back 0 for tests that customer might not have and I need to display if a testType has 0.

I am a lot more well versed in PhP then I am in MySQLi and SQL. Is there something I am missing here? Surely there has to be a better way to get all of this, maybe even get it in one query? Any suggestions or a point in the right direction would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple aggregation and a left join or two on your main query should do it.  A cross join could be used to identify the unique test types and by cross joining this to a customer/address 1:1 relationship  we generate a row for each test type for every customer.  That way each customer will have one of each type listed with the appropriate count (0) when no tests of that type exist for an account.

```
SELECT C.accountId, A.companyName, Z.TestType, Count(distinct T.TestID)
FROM Customers C
LEFT JOIN Address A
  ON C.addressId=A.addressId
CROSS JOIN (Select Distinct TestType from Tests) Z
LEFT JOIN Tests T
  on T.AccountID = C.AccountID
 and Z.TestType = T.TestType
 and ReceiveDT>=SomeDate
 and ReceiveDT<=SomeOtherDate
GROUP BY C.accountId, A.companyName, Z.TestType
```

LEFT Joinn will return all customer records and only those with address that match and only records from test matching a customer record.  So count will be 0 when no type/test match.

Customer:Address:TestTypes:Tests cardinality expected: 1:1:M:M

so if there were only 3 types of tests I would expect to see 3* the number of records in customers in the results.  This is because Address and customers appear to be a 1:1 the number of test types will determine how many times we replicate a customer record and the left join to tests is being aggregated so it will not add to the row count.

Obviously you can add a where clause if you need to limit to a specific customer, but I thought you wanted all customers's test type counts for all possible test types.

Comment: If I get the error `Column 'testType' in field list is ambiguous` What could be causing that.

Comment: Sorry needed to alias Z.TestType (in select and group by) after the cross join.

Comment: No problem, do I need to add `COUNT(distinct T.testId)` as well or no?

Comment: Not required but it would be more explicit.  It would be required if TestID exists in other tables however.

Comment: This is straight up wizardry! Wrote the statement to match my actual database and it does work. I have thousands and thousands of test so the query is taking very long to execute. Adding indexes may help this?

Comment: Awe thx.  no wizardy just straight up SQL.  An index on the joined key's would help: Also if TestType is in a separate table joining to it instead of the Select distinct list would help) (it wouldn't eliminate the cross join which is what's taking most of the time)

Comment: Quick follow up, if I had a recieveDate in my Tests table and I wanted to find tests between 2 different dates, any reason when I try to do this I am no longer getting back all types and counts. I am just getting back the types that have counts (not all of them even if its zero)

Comment: yep.  Left joins. you need to put the limiting criteria on the LAST join as and conditions otherwise the left join acts like an inner join.  Putting it in a where clause eliminates those records which are NULL since Null isn't between those dates thus the reason it needs to be on the join (and updated answer to include example)

Comment: Wow, you are a total life saver. Thank you for helping with this. The SQL you wrote is very easy to read and understand unlike a lot of answers I see on here with 50 lines of SQL for one query lol. TYSM!